# Moq с опцией CallBase: как создать инстанс класса с зависимостями в конструкторе?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, mocking

Допустим, у меня есть класс

```
 public class Foo 
 {
  public Foo(IBar bar)
  {
     //...
  }
  public virtual int GetValue(){}
  public virtual DoActual()
  {
       ...
     var value = GetValue();
       ...
  }
 }
```

Я хочу написать юнит тесты для него. Я планирую переопределить метод GetValue и возвращать нужное для теста значение. 
Пример:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var mock = new Mock<Foo>{ CallBase=true}; 
    mock.Setup(x=>x.GetValue()).Returns(1); 

    mock.DoActual();

 //asserts
}
```

Поскольку у Foo есть внешние зависимости в конструкторе, мне надо их как-то зарезолвить. Moq предлагает передавать зависимости в конструкторе Mock массивом:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
   var barMock= new Mock<IBar>();
    var mock = new Mock<Foo>(barMock){ CallBase=true}; // больше зависимостей, если надо, можно добавить через запятую после barMock
    mock.Setup(x=>x.GetValue()).Returns(1); 
    mock.DoActual();
 //asserts
}
```

Я обнаружил, что когда я передаю Mock в конструктор Mock, Moq бросает исключение, говорящее:

> Moq.Mock`1[IBar] is not that constructor of Foo accepting

Если в конструктор передать barMock.Object, ошибка изменится на следующую:

> Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
>    Castle.Proxies.IBarProxy

В общем я не понимаю, как создать инстанс Mock, когда у Foo есть зависимости в конструкторе, и я не хочу передавать в него инстансы реальных классов.

Answer (score 1):

Вот именно `barMock.Object` в качестве аргумента конструктора передавать и надо. Если конструктор не находится, то убедитесь, что подходящий конструктор существует и доступен.

У меня всё работает:

```
using Moq;
using static System.Console;

public class Program
{
    private static void Main ()
    {
        var barMock = new Mock<IBar>();
        var fooMock = new Mock<Foo>(barMock.Object) { CallBase = true };
        fooMock.Setup(x => x.GetValue()).Returns(1);
        fooMock.Object.DoActual();
        WriteLine("Done!");
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo (IBar bar) {}
    public virtual int GetValue () => 0;
    public virtual void DoActual () => WriteLine(GetValue());
}

public class Bar : IBar {}

public interface IBar {}
```

Comment: На английском стеке говорят тоже самое. Это очень странно :) У меня ошибка возникает не из-за того, что я передаю неверное количество параметров. Moq кричит, что я передаю ему proxy, а не объект класса.

Comment: Ну, судя по всему, у меня проблемы с поиском нужного конструктора, и это не стоит вопроса